# Value of the screen.width JS property

Tags: javascript, html, css

What does `screen.width` java-script property really holds? If it is just `device-width` which is as far as i know constant per device?

I'm a little confused because i noticed that changing device orientation (android phone) causes screen.width to change while everywhere i read `device-width` is constant.

Answer (score 0):

The `device-width` holds the fixed physical width of the device.
While the `screen.width` holds the rendering width of the screen.

The phone device, whatever the direction in which it's inclined, will still be the same device ; while the 'pixel space' in which the web page is rendered may double.

Maybe W3C explains this better, [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_screen_width.asp).

Cheers.